# Wikidata:SPARQL, Soccer players number of games

Tags: sparql, wikidata-query-service

I used this query at https://query.wikidata.org/ --

```sql
SELECT ?p ?pLabel (?oc as ?OC) (?sp as ?SP) WHERE {
                      
?p wdt:P106/wdt:P279* wd:Q937857. # Soccer player

SERVICE wikibase:label {bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" . }
                     
{ SELECT ?p (count(?oc) AS ?oc) WHERE { ?p wdt:P106 wd:Q937857; p:P106 ?oc. }  GROUP BY ?p HAVING(?oc<3)} # Occupation

{ SELECT ?p (count(?sp) AS ?sp) WHERE { ?p wdt:P106 wd:Q937857; p:P54 ?sp. } GROUP BY ?p HAVING(?sp>5)} # Sport Teams                                                                                                   
}

LIMIT 10
```

[Query link](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fp%20%3FpLabel%20%28%3Foc%20as%20%3FOC%29%20%28%3Fsp%20as%20%3FSP%29%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%0A%3Fp%20wdt%3AP106%2Fwdt%3AP279%2a%20wd%3AQ937857.%20%23%20Soccer%20player%0A%0ASERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7Bbd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20.%20%7D%0A%0A%7B%20SELECT%20%3Fp%20%28count%28%3Foc%29%20AS%20%3Foc%29%20WHERE%20%7B%20%3Fp%20wdt%3AP106%20wd%3AQ937857%3B%20p%3AP106%20%3Foc.%20%7D%20%20GROUP%20BY%20%3Fp%20HAVING%28%3Foc%3C3%29%7D%20%23%20Occupation%0A%0A%7B%20SELECT%20%3Fp%20%28count%28%3Fsp%29%20AS%20%3Fsp%29%20WHERE%20%7B%20%3Fp%20wdt%3AP106%20wd%3AQ937857%3B%20p%3AP54%20%3Fsp.%20%7D%20GROUP%20BY%20%3Fp%20HAVING%28%3Fsp%3E5%29%7D%20%23%20Sport%20Teams%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%7D%0A%0ALIMIT%2010)

After having googled for hours to find a way to sum the number of games (`P1350`) of each player in all teams (`P54`), I decided to ask for some help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```sql
SELECT ?player ?playerLabel ?totalMatchesPlayed {

SERVICE wikibase:label {bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" . }

{
  SELECT ?player (sum(?matchesPlayed) as ?totalMatchesPlayed) WHERE {
    ?player wdt:P106/wdt:P279* wd:Q937857 . 
    ?player   p:P54/pq:P1350 ?matchesPlayed.
  }
  GROUP BY ?player
  LIMIT 100
}

}
```